# Calculating running sum over partition in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to calculate a running sum over a partition. This seems easier and quicker than the method suggested in [BigQuery SQL running totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664578/bigquery-sql-running-totals).

For example:

> SELECT corpus,corpus_date,word_count,
>         sum(word_count) over (partition by corpus,corpus_date order by word_count,word DESC) as running_sum
>   FROM
>      [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]

I'm facing 2 problems:

1. I'm unable to let the sum start with the most common word (word with highest word_count). Setting DESC or ASC just doesn't change anything, and the sum starts with the least common word(s). If I change the order by to include only "order by word_count" than the running sum isn't correct since rows with the same order (== same word_count) yield the same running sum.
2. In a similar query I'm executing (see below), the first row of the running sum yields a sum of 0, although the field I sum upon isn't 0 for the first row. Why does this happen? How can I workaround the problem to show the correct running sum? The query is:

> select * from 
>   (SELECT 
>   mongo_id, 
>   account_id, 
>   event_date, 
>   trx_amount_sum_per_day, 
>   SUM (trx_amount_sum_per_day) OVER (PARTITION BY mongo_id,account_id ORDER BY event_date DESC) AS running_sum, 
>   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mongo_id,account_id ORDER BY event_date DESC) AS row_num 
>   FROM [xs-polar-gasket-4:publicdataset.publictable] 
>   ) order by event_date desc

Comment: To expedite question 2: Can you share a public dataset with a sample of the data?

Comment: I shared the data. See revised question 2 for the problematic query

Comment: thanks for sharing - and indeed, there is something that needs further investigation for question 2 (reporting it internally)

Comment: Can you please update, when relevant, on the status of this issue?

Comment: There's actually an issue with OVER, PARTITION, and floats - it's being fixed (thanks for the report!). While the fix gets to production a workaround is casting to integers, as in: SELECT SUM(INTEGER(ROUND(x))) OVER(PARTITION BY y ORDER BY o)

Comment: Has this issue been fixed in production? Is there a way to track this bug?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For question 1:

Change:

```
SELECT
  corpus, corpus_date, word_count, SUM(word_count)
OVER
  (PARTITION BY corpus, corpus_date
  ORDER BY word_count, word DESC) AS running_sum
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
```

To:

```
SELECT
  corpus, corpus_date, word_count, SUM(word_count)
OVER
  (PARTITION BY corpus, corpus_date
  ORDER BY word_count DESC, word) AS running_sum
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
```

(Original query is sorting by word, but you wanted to sort by word_count)

Comment: For anyone who is curious, this is equivalent to adding `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` after the `ORDER BY` piece of the `OVER` argument.